# Convert query to eloquent orm laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

I wanna to converting this query

```
select sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`)) from `table`
```

to Eloquent ORM for Laravel 5

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Comment: I try Table::sum( TIME_TO_SEC('duration') ) but it is shown this error: Call to undefined function TIME_TO_SEC()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with me:

```
Table::selectRaw('sum( TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`) ) as duration')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in what context but if I get you correctly , you want

```
select sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`)) from `table`
```

to be

```
DB::table('table')
->select(DB::raw('sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`))')
->get();
```